# Including files from google drive

Tags: input

Does someone knows how can I include a file from Google drive? Something like

```
\input{http://adress_to_myfile_at_GDrive.tex}
```

Comment: I don't think, that TeX will have access to the internet/build a socket to input content somewhere in the cloud ;-)

Comment: [The download package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/download/download.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: on windows and mac at least, can't you sync drive to a local folder tex could see?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the minimal example which should work, no extra packages are needed.

I created `webfile.tex` with the following content:

```
THIS IS THE WEB FILE.
```

I put it on my [webpage](http://sirrah.troja.mff.cuni.cz/~pavlik/webfile.tex).

In the main document, which is in my case `~/StackOverflow/ex2.tex`, use `\write18` to run shell command and `\immediate` to do it immediately. I recommend to use `\unexpanded`, if your link contains `~`, `#` etc. The document is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

Here is the main document.

And here will be the imported \texttt{webfile.tex} file, which I uploaded on my web page.

\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{wget -P ~/StackOverflow http://sirrah.troja.mff.cuni.cz/~pavlik/webfile.tex}}
\input{webfile}

\end{document}
```

Then compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape ex2.tex`

The result is

[image]

But this will still download the `.tex` file to your computer (download directory is specified by the `-P /some/dir/here` switch), there is imho no way to do it without downloading the file.